# CI - num_rows not returning a readable number

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Using CodeIgniter 3 and `num_rows()` does not return a readable number (it's empty) using `return`. The only way to make it show the actual number is if I use `print` or `echo` - but that breaks the functionality I need the function to have.

```
    public function count_notifications($user_id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->select("*")
            ->where("user_id", $user_id)
            ->order_by("time_received", "desc")
            ->get("members_notifications")
            ->num_rows();

        return $query;
    }
```

Why is it behaving like that?

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: @Ibu to return the amount of rows it can find. Currently it returns nothing.

Comment: This is shooting in the dark but have you tried `return (int) $query;` ?

Comment: @Ibu, `num_rows()` returns an int.

Answer (score 1):

`num_rows()` will always return some integer whether it be `int(0)` for no results or `int(4)`. I ran my own test that was very similar to yours because for a second I thought it might be possible (it wasn't).

You should go through the typical debugging routes. The only thing I can think of is that there is an error in your syntax or wording that is resulting in `get()` returning boolean (and maybe you don't see that as you have error reporting off).

**I'm not sure how you are *verifying* that the function isn't returning an integer but perhaps start there as your logic there might be the problem.**

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
public function count_notifications($user_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->where("user_id", $user_id)
             ->get("members_notifications");            
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

I really wouldn't expect it to be different than your code. But you can easily confirm whether `$query` is a `CI_DB_result` or a bool.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following way:

```
public function count_notifications($user_id)
{
     $query = $this->db->select("*")
            ->where("user_id", $user_id)
            ->order_by("time_received", "desc")
            ->get("members_notifications");

    return $query->num_rows();
}
```